# How to convert all html escaped characters in a tidied xhtml string, so it loads in an XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt, tidy

In a .net web application I talk to a 3rd party CMS api which gives back html. I need to convert it to well formed xml, so I use an .NET wrapper around HTML tidy. This generates a nice DOM, but things go wrong when characters such as `&nbsp;` are used.

I need those to be converted to their code format like `&#160;` in order for an XmlDocument to accept it.

Can't set any more options on the tidy wrapper other than making it XHTML. So with the string returned, I need to do some magic, but I think it will come down to regular expressions using a mapping of my own right?

Answer (score 1):

If your .NET wrapper lets you give tidy all the options possible on the command line and in its config file, you should get what you need by setting 'numeric-entities' and 'output-xml' both to 'true'.